# How should I read values from multi-field's subfield?

Tags: entities

I'd like to access values stored in a [Multifield](https://drupal.org/project/multifield) programmatically. I use a [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) to do some calculations based on these values.

My current solution utilizes `field_get_items(... ,'my_multifield')` which returns a data structure containing an array of (sub)fields. Of course, I could extract values from that data, but I wonder if there is a better solution.

I took a look at the multifield source code, especially the tests, but I could not figure it out. What is the intended method for reading values from multi-fields?

Comment: I edited the title since the question was catching close votes as primary opinion based. Never ask for the best way; it is subjective and depends from many factors that, once listed, would make the question too specific to be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

`field_get_items()` is the only function provided by core to help with this.

The [Entity module](https://drupal.org/project/entity) provides the `EntityMetadataWrapper` class, though, which makes these things a bit more palatable. E.g.

```
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
try {
  foreach ($node->field_my_field as $item) {
    $val = $item->value->value();
  }
}
catch (\EntityMetadataWrapperException $e) {
  // Recover...
}
```

That's about the simplest example there is, it would be worth reading the docs to find out how else you can use it.

Comment: Bear in mind that Multifield is currently labelled as 'unstable', so there may be something added for accessing its fields in some different way in the future

Comment: That is: the simpler way to answer the question. As alternative, wait for Drupal 8 and use its better API; I guess it is what I will do, before doing any serious work on entities and their fields.